# Django, want to update the form without having to open the form again

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I have a form called edit order. From my form there is a bit at the end where it updates the current item status date. It updates, but only if I was to close the form after clicking on the button called `save_status`. Is there a way where if I was to click on the button called `save_status`, then could the web page refresh itself without having to close the form? Some sort of auto-reload?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.ItemForm(request.POST, instance = item)
    if form.is_valid() and save_item is not None:
        form.save(True)
        request.user.message_set.create(message = "Item {0} has been updated successfully.".format(item.tiptop_id))
        return HttpResponse("<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">window.opener.location = window.opener.location; window.close();</script>")
    if request.POST.get('save_status'):
        item.current_item_status_date = date.today()
        item.save()
```

Comment: "form updates itself"?  What does this mean?  Please define this precisely.  DO you want the web page to refresh on the browser with new data?  Or do you want something else to happen?

Comment: @ S.Lott Yes, I do want the web page to refresh on the browser with new data

Answer (score 2):

I can't understand where you are having problems. You've updated the form - so now just send the updated form back to the context, rather than redirecting to a new page.